# C - Structure and user variables share same memory - possible?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Sorry for newbie question in C. I have following problem.

Let's say I have a structure of:

```
struct foo {
   char  var_a;
   char  var_b;
   char  var_c;
};
```

And a list of variables:

```
foo j;
char a, b, c;
```

I want to make sure, that in all moments of time j.var_a is equal to a, j.var_b equals to b and j.var_c equals to c. E.g I want that structure members would be also accessible like normal user variables at any moment. I thought that struct members just need to share the same memory locations with defined user variables, so assumed that something from this has to be defined as pointer and tried this:

```
foo *j;
char a, b, c;
```

And in main() function:

```
j = &a;
```

With the aim of assigning address of structure pointer to address of a and with assumption that a,b,c will be located in adjacent memory spaces. But compiler throws error obviously because I can't point pointer of one type to address of other type. I also feel this is unsafe as it relates to the order of variables in memory.

So is there a safe way to achieve this goal without manual reassignment each time when any of variables are changed and additional memory copying? I have an embedded target, so would like to save memory and processor time.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that `j = &a` will not do what you expect for the reasons you gave.

What you can do instead is define the members of `struct foo` to be pointers:

```
struct foo {
   char  *var_a;
   char  *var_b;
   char  *var_c;
};

char a, b, c;
foo j = { &a, &b, &c };
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. But the problem is that I really need to access `struct foo` members by `j.var_a` and so on - so does legacy code, which I can't change.

Comment: @syoma Then you're out of luck.  Something needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

`char a, b, c;` local variables are't guaranteed to be contiguous, in-order, and to exit in memory.

There's no way to robustly overlay a struct over them.

The closes thing you could do to pretending some local variables overlay a struct is to make those *"local variabled"* macros:

```
struct foo {
   char  var_a;
   char  var_b;
   char  var_c;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct foo j;
    #define a j.var_a
    #define b j.var_b
    #define c j.var_c

    /*now a,b,c are sort of like contiguous locals
      that overlay j */

    #undef a
    #undef b
    #undef c


}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try your suggestion. To let you know the variables are global.

Comment: @syoma if they're global and visible then your goal actually is achievable with some nonstandard linker tricks.

Comment: Maybe that's a point. Actually to make situation clearer - this is how these variables are defined in two different .c files and I have to link them together somehow, better without additional computational code.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some circumstances when it would be useful to be able to use "ordinary variable" syntax to access members of a structure (among other things, it may improve performance, allow code that saves/restores a program's state to be reduced to a single structure write/read, etc.) the closest C comes to allowing that is allowing the use of `#define` macros to replace the "variable" name with a reference to the structure.

For example,

```
struct foo { int foo_woozle, foo_moozle; } myFoo;
#define woozle myFoo.foo_woozle
#define moozle myFoo.foo_moozle
```

Unfortunately, this approach requires that the "variable" names not appear as tokens in any other context within the compilation unit.  If, for example, one tried to declare a structure with a member named `woozle`, the structure declaration would fail because its name would get replaced with `myFoo.foo_woozle`.

On some implementations it may be possible to do something like:

```
extern int woozle,boozle;
extern volatile struct foo myFoo;
```

and then use code written in another language (e.g. assembly) to overlay the objects as desired.  Unfortunately, this is likely to be unreliable unless optimizations are disabled or the objects are all qualified `volatile`.  The approach using `#define` will thus be able to generate more efficient code, but is unfortunately saddled with the ugly semantic limitations of macro substitution.

Comment: Hi supercat. Actually I didn't thought about defines like you and @PSkocik suggested. I will try this. Thanks!

Comment: Some stupid question about this - is it possible to do another way around? A.g. woozle and moozle are declared as real variables, but myfoo.foo_woozle would be obfuscated?

Comment: @syoma: That is not possible, unless the name of the structure and all member names are used exclusively for those purposes.  One could do something horrible like replace `myfoo` with `((0*sizeof somestruct` and `foo_woozle` with `somemember)[&woozle])` so that `myfoo.foo_woozle` would become `((0*sizeof somestruct.somemember)[&woozle])`, but in scenarios where that would work, it would almost certainly be easier to replace `myfoo.` with `myfoo_`.